# Which Ethereum user bought Beeple's "Crossroad" NFT video for $6.6 million?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, privacy, nft

we know the story of who bought Beeple's "Crossroad" NFT video for $67,000 and re-sold it on the secondary market for $6.6M worth of ETH, but who exactly was the person, or Ethereum username, that bought it from him for that amount? and on which secondary market, or NFT platform, did this sale occur on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beeple's CrossRoad was part of his [First Drop](https://niftygateway.com/itemdetail/primary/0x12f28e2106ce8fd8464885b80ea865e98b465149/1) collection on Nifty Gateway, which is where it sold for $67,000.

The $6.6m sale onto the secondary market was [brokered by Nifty Gateway](https://twitter.com/niftygateway/status/1364748740041523200). This basically just means that the first buyer left the artwork on retention with Nifty Gateway, and someone approached Nifty Gateway directly to buy it, meaning it wasn't re-auctioned.

Going the technical route to look at the ownership, from the [NFT's profile](https://niftygateway.com/itemdetail/secondary/0x12f28e2106ce8fd8464885b80ea865e98b465149/100010001) we can see that Beeple's NFT contract address is [0x12f28e2106ce8fd8464885b80ea865e98b465149](https://etherscan.io/address/0x12f28e2106ce8fd8464885b80ea865e98b465149), and that the tokenId of this particular NFT is 100010001.

Using Etherscan, we can interact with the contract address, [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x12f28e2106ce8fd8464885b80ea865e98b465149#readContract). Entering the tokenID into the `ownerOf()` method gives us an owner address of 0xE052113bd7D7700d623414a0a4585BCaE754E9d5.

This equates to the Nifty Gateway user [Delphina Leucas](https://niftygateway.com/profile/babybeluga) who was sent the NFT by the [anonymous $6.6m buyer](https://niftygateway.com/profile/anonymous10). (Of course, it could just be the same person... Or Nifty Gateway themselves... In fact, that address is [this](https://opensea.io/accounts/nifty-gateway-omnibus?embed=true%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fopensea.io%2Fassets%2F0x8c9b261faef3b3c2e64ab5e58e04615f8c788099%2F176299%2Fbid%3Freferrer%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fopensea.io%2Fassets%2F0x8c9b261faef3b3c2e64ab5e58e04615f8c788099%2F93957%2Fbid%3Fembed%3Dtrue) user on OpenSea... Make of that what you will.)

Comment: any idea the buyer information, and currency used, for the recent $69M win hosted by Makersplace and Christies? Makersplace doesn't display its blockchain history unlike other listings

Comment: The buyer was Justin Sun, the guy who runs the TRON blockchain, presumably as a publicity stunt. Let me see if I can work out the addresses and currency information...

Comment: The Christie's auction particulars includes the contract address and tokenID: https://onlineonly.christies.com/s/beeple-first-5000-days/beeple-b-1981-1/112924

Comment: You can query that contract for the tokenID in Etherscan (40913 - again from Christie's). That gives and owner address of 0xc6b0562605D35eE710138402B878ffe6F2E23807, which is actually one of Beeple's accounts. So it looks like ownership hasn't yet been transferred.

Comment: Correction: it wasn't Justin Sun, it was Metapurse -> https://twitter.com/metapurse/status/1370436982896259078